# Select statement within function blank results

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I'm using Postgresql and trying to have a select statement in a function to call out. At the moment the call gives me zero results

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_all_male_borrowers
(
OUT p_given_names varchar(60), 
OUT p_family_name varchar(60), 
OUT p_gender_code integer
)


RETURNS SETOF record as $body$
declare body text;

BEGIN
SELECT into p_given_names,p_family_name, p_gender_code
borrower.given_names, borrower.family_name, gender.gender_code

FROM BORROWER

INNER join gender on borrower.gender_code=gender.gender_code

WHERE borrower.gender_code = '1';

RETURN ;

END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call to function:

```
select * from f_all_male_borrowers()
```

What is missing, or what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_all_male_borrowers
(
OUT p_given_names varchar(60), 
OUT p_family_name varchar(60), 
OUT p_gender_code integer
)
RETURNS SETOF record as 
$body$
SELECT into p_given_names,p_family_name, p_gender_code
borrower.given_names, borrower.family_name, gender.gender_code
FROM BORROWER
INNER join gender on borrower.gender_code=gender.gender_code
WHERE borrower.gender_code = '1';
$body$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION f_all_male_borrowers()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Try this and then call :

```
select * from f_all_male_borrowers();
```

Before doing that you need to check whether your query have result or not !!

After creating function then:

```
Got to Functions->Right click your function(ie,f_all_male_borrowers())-> Scripts->Select Script ->Then run it.
```

If it returns result then your procedure is correct.